# SQL2019 with SQLENGINE installation 4 new system files are showing but no new system databases in SSMS

Tags: sql-server

After installing the *SQL2019 DEVELOPER edition*, build 15.0.4023.6 (with the following `FEATURES = SQLENGINE, FULLTEXT, CONN, IS`) it is noticed that installation is showing 4 new system database files:

- model_msdbdata mdf file
- model_msdblog log
- model_replicatedmaster log
- model_replicatedmaster mdf file.

But no such system DB is displayed in SSMS under system DBs.
Can you please advise further?

Comment: Are they listed in `select * from model.sys.database_files`?

Comment: Seems like an HA thing, "Additional model databases - model_replicatedmaster and model_msdb - are used to seed the replicated portion of the system databases. In addition to these databases, you will see containedag_master and containedag_msdb databases if you connect directly to the instance." [Deploy SQL Server Big Data Cluster with high availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/deployment-high-availability)

Comment: Hi, they are not listed under model.sys.database_files, only those two files: F:\MP\mydir\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\model.mdf
F:\MP\mydir\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf .IN my INI File I use the INSTALLSQLDATADIR flag for the data directory for SQL Server data files -so am looking  at the right place. No AlwaysOn enabled , stand alone server installation/configuration perfromed.

Answer (score 0):

sql does not list those db files in sys.master_files which is the sql dynamic management view that keeps a track of all the database files(whether system or user), when a database file is not referenced in this DMV it could be like a resource database which was created during the installation or could be something related to a new or upcoming feature. What i observed is that sql will have its handle on all the databases it houses, which means they are all actively associated with that sql instance, that means you simply cannot copy and paste the db files to a different location when sql has a handle on it. But these new db files are not locked, either they are meant to be cleaned up automatically by sql after setup is complete or it could be a bug, may be microsoft might release a patch to cleanup these files. This reminds me of a scenario when resource database was introduced along with system database sometime back https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/resource-database?view=sql-server-ver15
so maybe microsoft will come up with some documentation on these database files in future or they already have, but i could not find one yet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30643019)